# Calculating the runtime of the code

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

How to calculate the time complexity for the given pseudo code?? I want to know how it is calculated.

```
sum ← n + 351
for (int i = 1; i < n + 2; i++) do
    sum ← sum + i + 355 + A[i]
    for (int j = 0; j ≤ i; j++) do
        sum ← sum * A[j] + j
    end-for (j)
    sum ← sum + 352 * n
    for (int k = 0; k < n - 1; k++) do
        sum ← sum * k + A[k]
    end-for (k)
    sum ← sum + 2 * n + 354
end-for (i)
sum ← sum + 2 * n + 356
```

Comment: What do you mean by "calculate the runtime"?

Comment: We have to find out in form of T(n)!! @Pshemo

Comment: The best you can do is work out the time complexity.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Right, that's exactly what the OP is asking. She wants to know how to work out the time complexity (hence my retagging of the question).

Comment: By runtime, I refer to running time of an algorithm, as a function relating the input length to the number of steps (time complexity). @Pshemo

Comment: If you tried to it calculate yourself, where are your stuck at? What's the problem you face? That's how SO works.

Comment: Posting code as images is not optimal. Images are not searchable and it is less practical to read. Please consider rewriting the code - it might help you attract a good answer.

Comment: I will keep that in mind next time.. @ Anders :)

Comment: @Anders I did that for the OP.

Comment: @Olaf No need to close; homework questions are okay on SO: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253794/13

Comment: @Olaf This is not a homework question. I was solving my textbook exercises when I got struck on how to proceed with such examples.

Comment: @KatherineKewl: So "We" is [pluralis majestatis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Royal_we)?

Comment: I meant all of "US"... implying the one's helping me... Duh..!! @Olaf

Comment: @KatherineKewl: Sorry, but that is really a bad psychological trick trying to make **your** problem **ours**. And once people know it, it backfires to the asker (as it did here). If you really wrote this unintended, don't feel offended now, but please think about.

Comment: It was just me.. trying to solve together with all of you, not making it "your" problem.... Sorry too for making you feel it that way.. :) @Olaf

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young: How about http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253793/4774918 ?

Comment: @Olaf That explains how Robert does things, not how he thinks everyone else should do things. Shog's answer is higher-voted anyway, so it seems the community agrees with him more.

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young: OTOH, Robert is citing the help center. And the question here is definitively lacking the criterions. Anyway, I'm quite confident I learned to think on my own long time ago and try to use this ability since then. There is a good proverb about majorities: "Eat feces, millions of flys can't be wrong"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can look at the complexity of each loop.

The outer loop is order `n`

The inner loop also goes up to `n` (actually `i` which goes up to `n`)

So combined it is `O(n^2)`

Comment: What about the 3rd loop?? (the one in which k goes upto n-1)

Comment: @KatherineKewl Still O(n), so Peter's answer still applies.

Comment: The third loop gives you `O(n*2n)` (instead of `O(n^2)`) but that is simply `O(2n^2)`. Since 2 is constant (it does not depend on n) you can simplify to `O(n^2)`.

Comment: @KatherineKewl the second and third loops are O(n). O(n + n) is O(n)

Comment: @KatherineKewl No, it'd only be O(n³) if the `k` loop were nested _inside_ the `j` loop.

Comment: Oh.. I got it now. So it doesn't matter how many loops are inside the orignal loop... @PeterLawrey

Comment: @KatherineKewl The only thing which matters is the highest order loop.

Comment: @KatherineKewl You should still look at all the loops, but you'd take the highest-order one. For example, both the `j` and `k` loops are O(n), so the highest-order is still O(n).